# Prove the monotoniticy of a function $f$ which satisfies $f(x) e^{f(x)} =x$

Tags: calculus, functions, monotone-functions

Let $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying

$f(x) e^{f(x)} =x$ for every $x \geq 0$. Prove that $f(x)$ is monotone increasing.

I thought about taking the derivative of both sides, but I am not able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(u) = u e^u$. Then $g$ is increasing on $[0, \infty)$. Indeed, $g'(u) = e^u(1+u)$ is clearly positive for all $u \ge 0$.

A second observation is that $f(x) = x e^{-f(x)} \ge 0$ for all $x \ge 0$.

Now suppose that $f$ weren't increasing. Then there would exist $x, y \in [0, \infty)$ such that $x < y$ but $f(x) > f(y)$. Since $g$ is increasing on $[0, \infty)$ and $f(x), f(y) \ge 0$, then $g(f(x)) > g(f(y))$. But by hypothesis, we have $g(f(x)) = x$ and $g(f(y)) = y$, and so we get $x > y$, which is absurd. It follows that $f$ is in fact increasing.

Note: This proof doesn't even assume that $f$ is differentiable, or continuous or anything.

Answer (score 1):

The function

$$g(t)=te^t$$ is monotonic and continuous for $t\ge0$, and its codomain is $\mathbb R^+$.

Then $g$ is invertible and monotonic in $\mathbb R^+$.

Comment: I like the simpler answer here.

Comment: @SimpleArt You do realize that my answer is identical, and that I simply proved for the fact that 1/ $g$ is increasing and 2/ if an invertible function is increasing, then so is its inverse function? This answer is only simpler because it's hiding the proofs (I don't know who downvoted me, but if that was their reasoning... this isn't a great reasoning.)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi yes, there is definitely nothing actually different between these answers, but, as my head hearts due to children, the simpler answer got my vote.  And ofc, I didn't down vote you.  :)